# Crystal Report conversion from cm to inches

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

In my crystal report I have column values for `width` and `height`. I wanted them to be in `inches`. when I searched how to convert, I came across changing the settings in regional language etc. Even after doing all those it did not reflect changes.

Can anyone please help?

I am new to crystal report.

Comment: didn't get your problem... what exactly you are looking for? are Widht and Height are values in the column? or those are something different?

Comment: They are column names in my report

Answer (score 0):

```
1 cm = 0.15500030984252 in
```

what you could do is create 2 formulas, one for `width` and another for `height` , then do the conversion inside and replace your field for this formulas on their respective columns. For example, `WidthConverted(your width field*0.155)` and `HeightConverted(your height field * 0.155)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out `1 Inch` = `1440` Twips

For example if an object has `Width = 4725` and Height  = `1455'

Then its dimensions in inches are `W = 3.28 and H = 1.01`